# Incompatible GraphDef versions in Extend

Tags: tensorflow

I have some code which creates a graph to process some images and then iterates `sess.run()` in a loop to fetch batches of image tensors of shape [*, 299, 299, 3]. I'd like to then feed these images into the inception model.

So, I added some code to load the inception model:

```
def create_graph():
    """"Creates a graph from saved GraphDef file and returns a saver."""
    # Creates graph from saved graph_def.pb.
    print 'Loading graph...'
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        with gfile.FastGFile('/web/tensorflow_transfer/resources/classify_image_graph_def.pb', 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
            _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    return sess.graph

g = create_graph()

for i in range(training_steps):
  sess.run(...)
```

Now Im getting this error when running `run()`:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 368, in run
    results = self._do_run(target_list, unique_fetch_targets, feed_dict_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 420, in _do_run
    raise RuntimeError(compat.as_text(tf_session.TF_Message(status)))
RuntimeError: Incompatible GraphDef versions in Extend: 1 != 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely from using too old a version of TensorFlow to read in and run the graph -- the graph was created using a newer version of the GraphDef.  Try upgrading to 0.7 or to HEAD and then run your code again.